# Apache POI, how to modify conditional formatting range in Excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to resize range of conditional formatting.

Read an Excel file (.xlsm, .xlsx), modify ranges for conditional formatting, and save it as new file.

```
SheetConditionalFormatting sheetFormatting = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
for( int i = 0; i < sheetFormatting.getNumConditionalFormattings() ; i++ )
    for( CellRangeAddress region : 
            sheetFormatting.getConditionalFormattingAt(i).getFormattingRanges() )
        if( region.getFirstRow() == 1 )
            region.setLastRow( 1+data.length );
```

So I just get all conditional formatting objects, get range objects for them, and modify ranges by calling `CellRangeAddress.setLastRow()`.

The problem is that this modification is not present in result file. In fact, there are no changes in sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting() just after the operation.

Need I 'commit' somehow changes to `ConditionalFormatting`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should add Conditional Formatting to your sheet formatting.

```
sheetFormatting.addConditionalFormatting(newRange,arrayOfRules);
```